# How to expand the Navigation Drawer over the toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, navigation

I want to expand my Navigation drawer over the toolbar and make the status bar transparent. I read an introduction, that I must implement the toolbar into the XML File of my Drawer layout. I tried it out, but it doesn't work. 
Or is there a way, that I can change it from the styles folder? I tried a couple of introductions and tutorials, but they didn't work :/

That is the code of my Drawer Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
//(............)
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/navigationmenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white">
        </ExpandableListView>

        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And that is my app Bar Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.example.example.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/activity_navigation_view" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: try checking out this link http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/02/drawerlayout-navigation-drawer-view-over-android-actionbar-toolbar.html

Comment: @Kushan I tried it out, but it doeasnt hlped me